# to view all websphere MQ messages in JMS call

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, mq

I use JMS (Java Message Service API) in my java application to work with queues/topics residing on websphere MQ. I am looking for a tool/support pac which can show me all MQ Messages being called e.g. when I do queueConnectionFactory.createConnection(), it would have resulted into MQCONN/MQCONNX  call, so I need to see what excatly is being passed. So basically during my entire JMS based interaction, I want to see all MQ messages which are being passed to. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. When you say "MQ messages", do you mean messages, or MQI calls? What version of WMQ? It's true that fundamentally the JMS client maps to a set of MQI calls with appropriate options, e.g. createConnection() is more than a MQCONNX, MQINQ is done too, but why do you want to know these? And do you want to do it for every JMS call, or just once? There are ways to do it, but I think really only intended for WMQ development/service at Hursley

Comment: @strmqm: i meant to ask MQI calls along with parameters passed.....so basically as you mentioned "fundamentally the JMS client maps to a set of MQI calls", so I want to know of these....I am working in production support environment for  JMS based messaging to websphere MQ v6/v7. Sometimes, we spent lot of time debugging out issues...so wanted to check if we have any tool for this? It is basically correlation to for example if I work in hibernate, I would like to SQLs it generate.

Comment: I don't know of any public API/supportpac as such for this - i've done it in the past in v7 by turning on trace for just com.ibm.jmqi.* and using a regexp to split out the relevant calls from the trace file, the trace is very verbose but quite easy to read, but that's very much an occasional tool for development troubleshooting rather than anything suitable for production. AIUI there is an internal API for intercepting JMQI calls in v7 (eclipse finds com.ibm.mq.jmqi.monitoring) but it does not appear to be published for external use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using websphere, you can turn on tracing by going to WAS console and tracing service to enable jms logging.

Answer (score 1):

Trace tells you what APIs are being called. To a good extent trace helps. But beyond that call IBM help.

Comment: can you please eloborate? Can you please tell me how to enable trace?

Comment: java -Djava.library.path="%MQ_JAVA_LIB_PATH%" -Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status=ON -Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.outputName="%MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH%"\trace <jms application>

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JMS MQ client mode connection it is possible to run send/receive exits on the MQ SVRCONN channel to log the client MQI and message flows. The free IBM SupportPac MA0Z has this capability. This technique is not possible with a binding mode connection because there is no MQ channel involved.